# how to use cut command when string has =

Tags: bash

I have a flat file which has condition like this inside `password=Y9=hj4jd`. I want to cut the display only the value of password so I am using cut command like `cut -d = -f2` but it is giving value `Y9` only rather than whole value. Can anyone suggest what can be done to modify this?

Comment: `grep -oP '^.*?=\K.*'`

Comment: `sed 's/[^=]*=//'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the end field.

```
cut ... -f2-
```